# Approximation of a rational function

Tags: regression, approximation, polynomial

Suppose a function $f$ has a known form $ f(x) = \dfrac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ where both $P,Q$ are polynomials of degree at most $d$. Assume $d$ is fairly low, take $d\leq 5$ for example.

What is the "best" way to estimate the coefficients of $P,Q$ ?

A standard non-linear least-squares on a dataset of $n=100$ points yields the following fits for different datasets of size $n=100$ points from the same joint distribution.

[image: ratfit example]

There must be a smarter way of approaching this problem.

Comment: Do you really need to fit the separate polynomials? Or would it be enough to approximate the rational function $f$, say using a spline fit? If both $P$ and $Q$ are of degree up to 5, you would have 12 degrees of freedom if you really want to have a chance of including the true model in your search, that is a lot, especially if your $n=100$ is realistic. It may make sense to allow for some bias but reduce the variance by using a spline fit with only 3 or 4 degrees of freedom.

Comment: Is your objective really estimating the *coefficients,* or would it be to estimate $f$ itself within a given interval?  How will you assess the quality of the coefficient estimates?  (This is a thorny problem because the coefficients will change radically depending on how you represent the data, such as will result from standardizing them, for instance.)